# Stranger from US wants to send me 65 million dollars and asking for bank details

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, scams, wire-transfer

Some random stranger on Twitter followed me and I followed her back..
Then I received this message from her:

> "Thanks for the follow back. My name is Mrs Jimmy Joy from Canada, a cancer patient and also a widow, my condition is really deteriorating and is quite obvious as presumed by physicians, they said i may not live more than two months because the stage at which my cancer has gotten is very critical (Level 4), Please I would like to know you."

I told her about myself then she replied:

> "I`d love to share a good-news with you about uplifting Christian humanitary works that might be of interest to you,i wish to establish a Charity organisation to promote humanitary works in your community to help the less privilege and other cancer patient like me.please kindly contact me on my mail xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com or let me have yours so i can share the message with you."

She then said that she wants to donate her funds so I could donate it to a charity or help needy people. I then  asked how is she going to send funds to me.  She said that I'm going to get money from a company named Skyfield Securities and Financial Services.  She gave me their email and a letter that I have to send to them.  I emailed them and they asked me to fill this form ([it looks like a fake form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiamM.jpg)).

I searched for the company online but there was no company named Skyfield Securities and Financial Services.     Is it a scam? What should i do?

Comment: Yes, it's a scam.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam

Comment: Besides, a **COMPLETE STRANGER** offers to send you $65M.  Ask yourself why.

Comment: I know it is a scam but i want to know how will i get scammed if i send her my bank details....

Comment: Search the site based on the `scam` tag.  There are many related answers.

Comment: I know but dont know what will she do next i just want to sue the scammer by sending wrong details but still i dont know if i sent her my details then how will she scam me?? @RonJohn

Comment: I know but dont know what will she do next i just want to sue the scammer by sending wrong details but still i dont know if i sent her my details then how will she scam me?? @quid

Comment: Report the scam [to the appropriate authorities](https://www.usa.gov/online-safety) and let them handle catching or punishing the criminals. All you should do is disengage.

Comment: Point of order: Canada is not part of the US.

Comment: @Steve-O: https://www.theonion.com/perky-canada-has-own-government-laws-1819563891

Answer (score 13):

> Is it a scam?

Yes.

> what should i do???

Stop responding to scammers on the internet when they message you.

> How will I get scammed if I send my bank details?

It doesn't matter. You don't have to understand how the scam works in order for it to be a scam.  The real scam might not even involve your bank details. **They might be asking for your bank details to find out if you are someone who is foolish enough to send your bank details to a stranger telling you an obviously impossible story**, and once they have established that you are that kind of foolish person, they'll start the *real* scam. We're not the scammers;  we do not know what their scam is.

The usual way this scam works is that they promise you money, but, oh dear, there is a fee that has to be paid and we cannot pay it because of some legal reason.  Then once you pay the fee, there is a second fee. Or even better, an "official" who needs to be bribed, and if you pay the "bribe" then now the scammers know that you are someone who is willing to commit crimes for them, and so it goes.

But maybe they have a different scam going. We don't know. **Just ignore them.**

Under no circumstances should you attempt to "scam the scammers". These are not nice people; they are criminals who will not hesitate to harm you if they think there's a profit for them. **They cannot be scammed.**  Again, do not engage. Just ignore them. Their account will be deactivated eventually, and they'll create another fake account and move on to someone else.

Comment: They **can** be scammed.  Just not by n00bs who need help from money.SE.